# Constructing a CFG in Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: nlp, chomsky-normal-form

I'm trying to construct a CFG from this language:

```
{a^n b c^2n | n >= 1}
```

and if I understood it right, I got

```
S->aA, A->bcB, B->cS|c
```

but even if this would be correct, I weren't sure how to make a CFG in Chomsky Normal Form from this. Every rule I know already applies to this. So I think I made a mistake with my first CFG?

Comment: This language describes strings such as `abcc`, `aabcccc`, that is strings that have double the number of c's compared to the number of a's and a b inbetween. Your grammar can produce something like `abccabcc` which is not correct. Furthermore Chomsky Normal Form forbids the starting non-terminal symbol S to appear on the right of a rule.

Comment: Also, your grammar rules apply to an (almost?) right regular language, `(abcc)+` (in regex form).